# How to share JDBC DataSource cross flink operators?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to access database in multi operators. Current solution is to use `AbstractRichFunction` and manage datasource's lifecycle in `open` and `close` methods.

Here is my code:

```java
public class DbRichFunction extends AbstractRichFunction {
    private final DbConfig dbConfig;
    private transient DataSource dataSource;

    public DbRichFunction(DbConfig dbConfig) {
        this.dbConfig= dbConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        dataSource = dbConfig.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        dataSource.close();
    }
}
```

It would save resources if I could share same instance **cross tasks(same operator or not)** in same jvm. I'm not sure whether it would cause memory leak if I use static variable with reference counter.

Here is what I want to do:

```java
public class DbRichFunction extends AbstractRichFunction {
    private transient DataSource dataSource;

    public DbRichFunction() {
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        dataSource = DbConfig.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        DbConfig.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You paste the example of Your code ? Do You want to share the JDBC Source between separate operators or between different parallel instances of the same operator ?

Comment: @DominikWosiński Here is my code, I want to share the JDBC Source between separate operators, just for resources saving.

Comment: I think using static variable with JDBC driver, while it should be possible from technical point of view, will cause a lot of issues with serialization. Did You make the benchmarks of You application? Because this might be a premature optimization to be done and can cause more bad than good.